# Stop 2 Instances of an Ajax form on the same page interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've the following form twice on my homepage:

```
<form id="get-consultation-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');" >
    <h3 class="sub-heading">Book a Consultation</h3>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" maxlength="" name="Consultation[name]" placeholder="NAME" />
        <input type="text" maxlength="" name="Consultation[number]" placeholder="NUMBER" />
        <input type="text" maxlength="" name="Consultation[email]" placeholder="EMAIL" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form uses jQuery/Ajax/PHP to forward the data via email:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#get-consultation-form").submit(function() {

        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://novicecoder.co.uk/priestley/consultation-process.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {

                $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                NProgress.set(0.0);

                if (msg === 'OK') {

                    result = '<div class="thanks" id="thanks">Thank you, we will contact you <span>shortly.</span></div>';

                    $(this).find("#fields").hide();
                    NProgress.set(0.5);

                    $("#message").hide();
                    $("#message").html(result).slideDown(100);
                    $("#message").html(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = msg;
                    $("#message").hide();
                    $("#message").html(result).slideDown(200);
                    $("#message").html(result);
                }
                    NProgress.set(1.0);
                });
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

The first form is working perfectly, however as you'll see in my working example, the 2nd is not:

[My website](http://novicecoder.co.uk/priestley/)

Any ideas why this is happening????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are unique. 
Try to change form elements to diferent ids. 
Or instead use classes.

If you use classes you can use $('.messages-class').closest() inside the form submit() for only interact in the current form.

Comment: Can you shed some light on how I would use .closest() in this instance please? I've never used closet() but I understand it scales up the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an element with the same ID on a page twice. Replace your `#get-consultation-form` ID with a class, that should solve your issue. This also applies to the elements within the form like `#fields` and `#message`.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I believe you helped me yesterday as well :)

Comment: @SamHolguin That's correct, I see that the site is coming along nicely.